# How to limit jQuery appending to form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added this link for adding new row to my form:

```
<a id="add" class="btn btn-info" style="color:white">New row</a>
```

And here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var i = 1;
            if(i == 1){
                $('#add').click(function(){
                    i++;
                    $('#dynamic_field').append("HERE GOES THE ROW ELEMENTS");
                });
            }
        });
```

And it works fine.

But I need to determine that add new row only one time and not several times.

So I tried checking `if(i == 1){` in the jQuery, but does not seem to be working and user still can adds new row multiple times.

So how can I limit this to only one time?

Comment: If you don't want the user to be able to append multiple times you can do 2 things, 1: Move the `if` statement inside your click event. Or unbind the click event after append

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Could u please show me how to unbind the click event after the append

Comment: You bind a click event with `.on('click', function` in jQuery, removing it is done with `.off('click'` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use [one](https://api.jquery.com/one/) with click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#add').one('click', function(){
    $('#dynamic_field').append("HERE GOES THE ROW ELEMENTS");
  });
});
```

This will invoke click event only once.

Answer (score 0):

Kiran 's answer, which is the better approach in my opinion, but I tried to extend your code with n times.

```js
const unbindEventWithParam = (n, fn) => {
  let i = 0
  function addRow(event){
    console.log('event is running')
    i++
    fn()
    if(i == n) return $(this).off(event.type)
  }
  return addRow
}
const addRow = unbindEventWithParam(2, function(){
  $('#dynamic_field').append("add row 1 ")
})
const addRow1 = unbindEventWithParam(4, function(){
  $('#dynamic_field1').append("add row 2 ")
})
$('#add').click(addRow)
$('#add1').click(addRow1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="add" class="btn btn-info">New row</a>
<div id="dynamic_field"></div>
<a id="add1" class="btn btn-info">New row1</a>
<div id="dynamic_field1"></div>
<button id="new-event">New event</button>
```